# SimpleOrientationSensor returning Null

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, .net-4.5

I'm using SimpleOrientationSensor to get the screen orientation information in my application. I'm testing this application in Windows Simulator but I always get the sensor object's value as null.

This is what I'm doing:

```
SimpleOrientationSensor sensor;

sensor = SimpleOrientationSensor.GetDefault();
if (sensor != null)
{
     sensor.OrientationChanged += sensor_OrientationChanged;
}
```

I understand that SimpleOrientationSensor.GetDefault() will return null when there is no Sensor available. Should I tweak the Simulator to get the sensor information? Or does it even handle these changes?

Comment: Show the functionality of SimpleOrientationSensor.GetDefault(), you need to debug this function to see why is it returning null.

Comment: @Furqan Safdar - SimpleOrientationSensor.GetDefault() is a framework method in WinRT that returns the default sensor of this type.  It sounds as if the simulator doesn't support this sensor, and so the method is returning null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/microsoft-windows-simulator-rotation-and-resolution-emulation/) the simulator doesn't support the `SimpleOrientationSensor` class.

> The Simulator doesn’t support the emulation of Orientation Sensor, and is only able to trigger a display orientation change.

Comment: Thank You. They should have fixed it in the Visual Studio 12